Custom Shock Absorber
I have tried making a custom shock absorber, but every option I see uses springs or is too bulky. Is there any way to make a custom LEGO shock absorber using rubber bands? I'm thinking of 6x1 studs with medium stiffness.

Hi William and welcome to Bricks.SE! Can you give more details regarding your goal? What are your dimension constraints, how much weight should it hold, what travel length are you looking for?

I want medium strength, and the dimensions are 6x1

6 as the overall length is quite restrictive, but something like this could be adapted to work if sandwiched between other parts that restrict non-axial movements:

where the black pieces are 1xX plates, red are 1x1 tiles, pink are 2x1 tiles, grey are Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin Hole on Top and the purple line is a rubber band.
The length of the black pieces would have to be negative if the total length needs to be 6, but if the symmetric assemblies can be put besides each other (thus violating the 1 module diameter constraint), then by using 4x1 plates you'd get 2 travel length.

I'll suggest using surgical rubber tubing as the dampening element:

(Photo from flickr)
Surgical rubber tubing is inexpensive and available in several thicknesses, so you can regulate the stiffness of the shock absorber. Just make sure that its internal diameter is 5mm so it fits around a technic axle.
An example assembly would be a 6-stud-long technic axle plus an angled technic connector, a bush, and a 1x1 brick with technic hole:

...then cut two lengths of rubber tubing and place them above and below the 1x1 brick.

If you really want to use rubber bands, then you can leverage parts 32039 (angled axle connector) and 27940 (3L bar with perpendicular pin hole) to add symmetrical rubber bands, like so:

